# mod_rewrite prevent repeating backreference

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to match a single reference in a URL to pass to a script, while retaining the rest as the path to the script. For example:

```
#/scripts/paramater/foo/bar.php should call
#/scripts/foo/bar.php?id=parameter
RewriteRule ^scripts/([^/]+)/(.*)$ scripts/$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However my backreference is matching multiple times. $2 only contains "bar.php" and $1 is somehow repeating for "parameter" and "foo".

How can I prevent the backreference from repeating itself?

**Edit:**
I've narrowed down the problem somewhat by fiddling with the second part of the rewrite rule.

```
#This doesn't work, as above
#Outputs: scripts/bar.php?id=foo?id=parameter
RewriteRule ^scripts/([^/]+)/(.*)$ scripts/$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]

#This works
#Outputs: foo/bar.php?id=parameter
RewriteRule ^scripts/([^/]+)/(.*)$ $2?project_slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which confuses me even more! Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy: add condition that will prevent execution of rewrite rule on already rewritten URL.

I see 2 main approaches (based on your URL examples):

**1. Will prevent rewriting if URL was already rewritten by the same rule:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^project_slug=
RewriteRule ^scripts/([^/]+)/(.*)$ scripts/$2?project_slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

On initial rewrite iteration URL will be rewritten and query string will have `project_slug=` at the start of the string. On next iteration the condition will not allow rewriting because query string already starts with `project_slug=`.

Of course, this approach will not work if original URL (before rewriting) has query string that starts with `project_slug=` (e.g. `/scripts/parameter/foo/bar.php?project_slug=hello`) .. which should not happen under normal circumstances (unless someone knows how rewrite rule works and is messing around on purpose).

**2. Allow rewrite execution ONLY on first iteration (regardless of which rule has rewritten this URL):**

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^scripts/([^/]+)/(.*)$ scripts/$2?project_slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately the variable used here `%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is not populated on every Apache build/setup. Therefore it may work fine on your setup but may not on another hosting. Unfortunately I cannot tell you how to determine (configure your Apache) if it will work without executing some sort of rewrite test.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise rewrite rules could run more than once. Your first solution works perfectly